# How to draw different language text on the image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I am doing a project where I need to translate the text into other Indian languages

I have tried few codes but the result I get for languages other than english is `empty boxes`

Original image:

[image: original image]

```
this is the variable output

[([[217, 25], [1061, 25], [1061, 61], [217, 61]],
  'He was in his bedroom: He smelled food, The food smelled',
  0.7254911849154941),
 ([[181, 70], [1006, 70], [1006, 114], [181, 114]],
  'like chicken: It smelled good. A neighbor must be cooking',
  0.773367181175143),

I am using the output coordinates for drawing a rectangle around the text
```

**1 - first code**

```
image = cv2.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/image_text_3.jpg")

color = (0, 0, 255)
  
# Line thickness
thickness = 1

fontpath = "/content/VANAVIL-AvvaiyarRegular.otf"     
TEXT_Font = ImageFont.truetype(fontpath, 20)

TEXT_SCALE = 0.85
TEXT_THICKNESS = 1

TEXT = "இனிய பிறந்தநாள் வாழ்த்துக்கள் யோஷினி குட்டி"

for bound in output:
    tl, tr, br, bl = bound[0]

    tl = (int(tl[0]), int(tl[1]))
    tr = (int(tr[0]), int(tr[1]))
    br = (int(br[0]), int(br[1]))
    bl = (int(bl[0]), int(bl[1]))

    cv2.rectangle(image, tl, br, color, thickness)
    
    text_size, _ = cv2.getTextSize(TEXT, TEXT_Font, TEXT_THICKNESS)

    text_origin = (tl[0] - text_size[0] / 2, br[1] + text_size[1] / 2)

    cv2.putText(image, TEXT, (tl[0], br[1]), TEXT_Font, TEXT_SCALE, (0,255,0), TEXT_THICKNESS, cv2.LINE_AA)
 
cv2.imwrite('centertext_out.png', image)
```

This is the error I get for the above code for tamil language

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-103-1d8c09103798> in <module>()
         26     cv2.rectangle(image, tl, br, color, thickness)
         27 
    ---> 28     text_size, _ = cv2.getTextSize(TEXT, TEXT_SCALE, TEXT_THICKNESS)
         29 
         30     text_origin = (tl[0] - text_size[0] / 2, br[1] + text_size[1] / 2)
    
    TypeError: an integer is required (got type FreeTypeFont)
```

**2 - second code for marathi**

```
fontpath = "/content/Devnew.ttf"
img=cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/image_text_3.jpg')
b,g,r,a = 0,255,0,0
font = ImageFont.truetype(fontpath, 32)
img_pil = Image.fromarray(img)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_pil)
draw.text((50, 80),  "जन्मदिन मुबारक", font = font, fill = (b, g, r, a))
img = np.array(img_pil)

cv2.imwrite('result.png', img)
```

Result of code 2:

[image: result of code 2]

**3 - Third code**

```
image = cv2.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/image_text_3.jpg")

TEXT = "जन्मदिन मुबारक हो योशिनी कुट्टी"
color = (0, 0, 255)



# Line thickness
thickness = 1
b,g,r,a = 0,255,0,0

TEXT_SCALE = 0.9
TEXT_THICKNESS = 1

fontpath = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Devnew.ttf"
font = ImageFont.truetype(fontpath, 20)
img_pil = Image.fromarray(image)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_pil)
draw.text((50, 80), TEXT, font = font, fill =(b,g,r,a))
image = np.array(img_pil)


cv2_imshow(image)
```

Result of code 3:

[image: result of code 3]

I don't understand whether there is a problm with the font file or the code or the image. kindly help in resolving. Thankyou!

**My main concern is to put the text inside the rectangle box created in the initial step({cv2.rectangle(image, tl, br, color, thickness} from code 1))**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the problem is with the `.otf` and `.ttf` files you are using. Try using the default `lohit-tamil` fonts from `/usr/share/fonts/truetype`. They can be installed with `sudo apt install fonts-indic` if they are not installed already. Use Unicode fonts only or download other Unicode fonts online - e.g. [Latha.ttf](https://www.freetamilfont.com/download.php?id=736045)

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image

img = np.zeros((200,1200,3),np.uint8)

fontpath = "tamil/Latha.ttf"
text = "இனிய பிறந்தநாள் வாழ்த்துக்கள் யோஷினி குட்டி"

font = ImageFont.truetype(fontpath, 32)
img_pil = Image.fromarray(img)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_pil)
draw.text((50, 80),text, font = font)
img_tamil = np.array(img_pil)

cv2.imwrite('tamil.jpg', img_tamil)
```

[image: tamil.jpg]